# PHP str_replace bypass

Tags: php, str-replace

I have concerns about the safe use of the function `str_replace`. 
E.G.

```
$var = "abcdeefghij";
$var = str_replace("ee", "", $var); // Should be "abcdfghij"
```

Is it possible to bypass (get "abcdeefghij" - with 2 'e' letters) this by multibyte charset or null character for example?

EDIT:
I was thinking about something like this: abcd%6565fghij %6565 would be replaced by ee but `str_replace` wouldnt work because it is multibyte string (`mb_str_replace`).

Comment: Are you removing more than one string using this approach, for example "ee" and "ff"?

Comment: not, only one.. (Were you thinking about "abcdeeeffeeefghij"?)

Comment: I think you need to clarify what this is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, if `ee` does not occur in the string in exactly that way, which means in a compatible encoding and without additional invisible characters, it won't match. As far as compatible encodings go, `ee` in your source code is likely ASCII, so any ASCII compatible encoding will do (incl. Latin-1, UTF-8 and most single-byte encodings). If there are other characters/bytes in-between, it's obviously not the same string and won't match. Other lookalike characters obviously won't match either.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this: abcd%6565fghij
%6565 would be replaced by ee but str_replace wouldnt work because it is multibyte string (mb_str_replace)

Comment: @non Well, that's obviously a very different string that won't match. And that string is not equal to `abcdeefghij` in any way, *except* if you URL-decode it *after* your `str_replace`. Obviously, don't do that. First decode the string from any encoded format it may be in, *then* do any replacements on the resulting final form. As for multi-byte, no, `%6565` is not valid to begin with, only `%65%65` would be. Whatever else you're thinking you're probably misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿sıɥʇ ǝʞıן uɐǝɯ no⅄

yes, it may be possible to "inject" an "e" character by entering a Unicode character that *looks* like `e` but is a different one. That danger is always there, any you may never be able to detect *any* character that resembles "e".

It's impossible to tell whether that's an actual problem though without knowing what you're trying to do. Usually, this should not be security relevant. Maybe provide some more background?

Comment: I asked because there are some functions that sometimes works in a different way than they should, by adding one character for example

Comment: @non sure - as deceze says, if you add an invisible or zero length character to `ee`, it will no longer match. But that is by design of course - to give you good advice about what to do, we need to know more about what you are doing.

Comment: I know this is what I wrote is very vague, but I cant tell you any more.. I only want to know is there any trap in this function